# How do I find the index of items structure

Tags: python

How do I find the index of items in this structure using python?

```
[{'symbol':'ETHUSD'} , {'symbol':'BTCUSD'}]
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did not provide any details at all, here is a simple solution.

```
l = [{'symbol':'ETHUSD'} , {'symbol':'BTCUSD'}]
target = "BTCUSD"

for index, element in enumerate(l):
    if element["symbol"] == target:
        print(index)
```

Comment: But as he/she did not provide any details at all, how can you then provide any solution? You are assuming this is a solution. :)

Comment: I provided a solution that finds the index of an item of the list, based on the value of the only key the items contain. But yeah, I see what you mean ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation

You have a list `[ ]`

Inside of the list you have 2 dictionaries `{ }`

Each dictionary contains a `key` and `value` pair.

---

### Lists

You can view items in a list by their index value

Let's take this simpler code to start with.

```py
my_list = ['apple','oranges','grapes']
```

Just keep in mind, *the index begins with 0*

So to access `grapes` you can do the following:

`print(my_list[2])`

Output: `grapes`

---

### Dictionaries

Dictionaries are stored as {"KEY":"VALUE"} pairs

You access the value, using the KEY.

For example:

`my_dict = {'name':'kaleb'}`

to find the VALUE of 'name' you use the KEY

`print(my_dict['name'])`

Output: `kaleb`

---

### Now back to your code

Remember, you have a list that contains 2 dictionaries

`my_list = [{'symbol':'ETHUSD'} , {'symbol':'BTCUSD'}]`

So say for example you wanted to access `BTCUSD`

To do so you first need to access the second item in the list, which has an index of 1. Remember index begins with 0

`my_list[1]`

This gets you to the second dictionary in the list, now you access the `BTCUSD` VALUE using the KEY

`['symbol']`

Putting it all together you get

```py
value = my_list[1]['symbol']
print(value)
```

Output: `BTCUSD`

Comment: please don't shadow keywords, use `array` , `list_of_items` or anything else but not `list`

Comment: yup, overlooked it. I edited the post.

Comment: Would list_of_list_items properly describe the structure or list_of_dictionarie_list?

Comment: list_of_dictionaries or list_of_dicts might be better.